# get crash while deleting row from database

Tags: ios, sqlite

i use this code for this thing

this is header

```
#import "SQLAppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "Coffee.h"

static sqlite3 *database = nil;
static sqlite3_stmt *deleteStmt = nil;

@implementation SQLAppDelegate
```

this is the method for deleting

```
- (void) removeCoffee:(NSNumber *)coffeeObj {

  NSLog(@"coffeeObj%@",coffeeObj);
    NSInteger myInteger = [coffeeObj integerValue];
    int i = [coffeeObj integerValue];
    NSLog(@"myInteger%d",myInteger);
    NSLog(@"i%d",i);
  // this print index number of the row which was selected 
    if(deleteStmt == nil) {

        const char *sql = "delete from Coffee where coffeeID = ?";
    //coffeeID is primary key it will be like 0,1,2,3,4...


        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &deleteStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
```

//in below line it get crashed with error which is at the end of question

```
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    //When binding parameters, index starts from 1 and not zero.
    sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStmt, 1, myInteger);

    if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteStmt)) 
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    sqlite3_reset(deleteStmt);



    [coffeeArray removeObjectAtIndex:myInteger];
}
```

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while creating delete statement. 'out of

please help me how to come out of this problem

Comment: hey that is not the full log what is there after 'out of?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant to say that the error is "out of memory" then this usually means that you have not actually opened the database. Make sure your `database` variable is referencing a database connection that is actually open.